# Combining continuous new lines based on a list in Python

Tags: python, list, algorithm

I am trying to create a function that will continuous new lines based on a list in Python.
For example, I have a list:
[image]

I want my function to output this:
[image]

I have a function already however its output is wrong:

```
final_list = list()
for sentence in test:
    if sentence != "\r\n":
        print(sentence)
        final_list.append(sentence)
    else:
        #Check if the next sentence is a newline as well
        curr_idx = test.index(sentence)
        curr_sentence = sentence
        next_idx = curr_idx + 1
        next_sentence = test[next_idx]
        times = 0
        while next_sentence == "\r\n":
            times += 1
            combine_newlines = next_sentence * times
            next_idx += 1
            next_sentence = test[next_idx]
            continue
        final_list.append(combine_newlines+ "\r\n")
```

[image]

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby` to group consecutive items of the same value, and then join the grouped items for output:

```
from itertools import groupby

print([''.join(g) for _, g in groupby(test)])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
test = [
    'I will be out',
    'I will have limited',
    '\r\n',
    '\r\n',
    '\r\n',
    'Thanks,',
    '\r\n',
    'Dave',
    '\r\n',
    '\r\n',
]

final_list = []
for e in test:
    if e != '\r\n':
        final_list.append(e)
    else:
        if len(final_list) == 0 or not final_list[-1].endswith('\r\n'):
            final_list.append(e)
        else:
            final_list[-1] += e
```

prints

```
['I will be out', 'I will have limited', '\r\n\r\n\r\n', 'Thanks,', '\r\n', 'Dave', '\r\n\r\n']
```

Explanation: Iterate over your items `e` in `test`, if they are not equal to `\r\n`, simply append them to the `final_list`, otherwise either append them to `final_list` or extend the last element in `final_list` based on if it ends with `\r\n`.

Comment: Thank you for this. This works! However it gives an error when the first part of the sentence is a newline, or when the whole text is just a new line.